# Count rows in excel with certain value

Tags: excel

I need to count the number of rows in an excel spreadsheet that contains the number 1.

```
-     A     B      C
1     0      0     1  
2     0      0     0
3     0      1     0
```

It would look somewhat like this, except with around 1000 rows.

Any help is great!

Comment: If there are more than one 1s in a single row, would you count them as 1 unit?

Comment: If there is only a single `1` per row, you can use a simple `SUMIF`. What have you tried to solve this problem, and where have you run into trouble?

Answer (score 0):

To count any value attending to some criteria you can use COUNTIF(cells,criteria)

More details here: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/countif-function-e0de10c6-f885-4e71-abb4-1f464816df34

Hope it helps